# java.lang.ClassCastException: [D cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Tags: java

I wrote the following code and not able to cast Object to Double.

```
Object[] args = new Object[3];
args[0]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
args[1]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField3.getText());
args[2]=Double.parseDouble(jTextField5.getText());
Object[] a = proxy.returningFeval("Combined", 1, args);
Double[] stra = new Double[a.length];
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    stra[i] = (Double)a[i];
    System.out.println("The value is :"+stra[i]);
}
```

Comment: `[D` is a `double[]`, not a `Double`.

Comment: It's hard to help you when we can't see what `proxy.returningFeval` does. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: "not able to cast Object[] to Double[]" No - you're not able to cast an `Object` to a `Double`.

Comment: proxy.returningFeval function is used to call a matlab function and it's return type is double  - @Jon Skeet

Comment: Please try to reproduce it *without* that... because if it were returning just `double`, how could it be assigned to an `Object[]`?

Comment: The value returned by Matlab function is double but it is casted into Object as the return value of returningFeval is always Object[]

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what the actual types of the elements of `a` are - all I can tell is that at least one of them is a `double[]`, rather than a `double` or a `Double`.

If you expect everything in `a` to be `double[]`s, you can simply change the cast to

```
double[] straArr = (double[]) a[i];
```

and then print using

```
System.out.println("The value is :"+Arrays.asString(straArr));
```

However, if the elements are heterogeneously-typed, you will need to use `instanceof` checks:

```
if (a[i] instanceof double[]) {
  // ...
} else {
  // Handle other types.
}
```

Comment: Thank you :). It worked . @Andy Turner

Answer (score 0):

In general you can break execution in the line with assignment, evaluate the expression (in your case this is: `proxy.returningFeval("Combined", 1, args)`) and recognize the actual type of returned value.